# Getting Uncaught TypeError: array_name[while_counter] is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am getting a perplexing error when running the following code:

```
while (typeof array1[while_counter] != undefined && while_counter <= while_counter_end) {
    console.log (array1);
    console.log (while_counter);
    
    $('#element_'+array1[while_counter]['key1']).on('click', function( event ){
```

This leads to `Uncaught TypeError: array1[while_counter] is undefined` for the line with jQuery. At the same time, the console.log lines output an array and the while_counter numbers. `console.log(array1[while_counter]);` in the loop also outputs the expected output.

Also, this happens only on a live website I have at a webhost, while running it on a local site doesn't result in this error.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: `typeof` operator always return a string

Comment: As mentioned above, typo: `undefined` should be `'undefined'`

Answer (score 0):

Just try debugging it with better logs

1. Print array1[while_counter] and array1[key1] in console log too.
2. is there any chance same code executing 2 time? First  when array1 is without actual value
3. use correct comparison operator i.e. use !== instead of !=

```
while (typeof array1[while_counter] !== 'undefined' && while_counter <= while_counter_end) {
```